# Unrecognized element 'autoDiscover' in web.config thrown by Azure Web Role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-caching

I'm trying to use the [Session State Provider for Windows Azure Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185668.aspx) on a co-located cache running on two instances of a Web role. I have a ASP.NET MVC4 project. I followed [Microsofts guide](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/) on how to set it up, and gone through it multiple times but with the same result. When I publish to Azure, I get a YSOD on every page.

I've gone through the logs on my Azure instance and found the exception that is probably causing this:

```
Event code: 3008 
Event message: A configuration error has occurred. 

...

Exception information: 
    Exception type: DataCacheException 
    Exception message: ErrorCode<ERRCMC0003>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Error in client configuration file.
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.ConfigFile.ThrowException(Int32 errorCode, Exception e)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.ClientConfigReader.Init(String path)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactoryConfiguration..cctor()

Unrecognized element 'autoDiscover'. (E:\sitesroot\0\web.config line 20)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.ClientConfigReader.Init(String path)
```

I realize that this has to do with my web.config and this section:

```
<dataCacheClients> 
  <tracing sinkType="DiagnosticSink" traceLevel="Error" /> 
  <dataCacheClient name="default"> 
    <autoDiscover isEnabled="true"/> 
  </dataCacheClient> 
</dataCacheClients>
```

But that section is taken straight from the Microsoft guide. I've also tried to uninstall and re-install the WindowsAzure.Caching Nuget-package, which adds the proper entries to the web.config, but it looks exactly the same as well.

I've found [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/windowsazuredata/thread/9fd2a66d-2c59-4c06-bf6c-96595622bbbc) on MSDN about what looks to the be the same issue, but I spinn up a new Azure web role, so I cannot see that it should be related to the GAC and an old version of the SDK in this case, or am I missing something?

Looking through the bin-folder of the deployed site, on my Azure instance, I see that the file version of my `Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core.dll` is `1.0.4621.0`. That is the same files that gets referenced in my project when i install the `WindowsAzure.Caching` Nuget-package. Is this the proper files to use?

After 15 hours of debugging, any input on this would be highly appreciated.

**Update:**

I've actually gotten [this project](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Azure-Caching-78a49b70) to work, when I publish it to two instances of a new Web role. I'll start to go through that deployment and see if I can spot any differences.

**Update 2:**

The difference is that my project uses version `1.0.4621.0`of `Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core.dll`, while Microsoft's project uses `1.0.4655.0`. So it could actually be that I'm using an old version of the SDK. For some reason my project insist on uploading those files when I publish, even though I delete them, but I'll get back with a complete answer if this solves the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try upgrading the latest **Azure SDK** to **1.7 SP1** or **1.8**. [Azure SDK 1.8 was just released this week](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/10/29/list-of-components-installed-with-windows-azure-sdk-1-8.aspx). [According to MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/9fd2a66d-2c59-4c06-bf6c-96595622bbbc), `autoDiscover` is only supported in **Azure SDK 1.7.1+** for [role-based caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131262.aspx).

**[Azure SDK 1.6](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28045)** (*November 2011*) Assembly Version: `1.0.4617.0`
**[Azure SDK 1.7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29988)** (*June 2012*) Assembly Version: `1.0.4621.0`
**[Azure SDK 1.7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30651)** (*June 2012 SP1*) Assembly Version: `1.0.4655.0`
**[Azure SDK 1.8](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35448)** (*October 2012*) Assembly Version: `1.0.4797.0`

Comment: Thank you for that! I got around the exception by upgrading to 1.8, as you suggest. That versions causes another exception unfortunately, but I'll post it as another question all together in case I can't solve it. Thanks!